# Find lines that contain two different strings and then write these lines into output file using sed

Tags: sed

I want to find lines that contain two different strings, then write these lines into an output file.
INFILE be like:

```
clk_a,start_point,end_point,clk_b,0.5
clk_b,start_point,end_point,clk_a,0.5
clk_a,start_point,end_point,clk_c,0.5
clk_a,start_point,end_point,clk_d,0.5
```

I use the following command to find the desired lines, but it doesn't work. What's wrong with my command?

`sed -n '/clk_a.*clk_b|clk_b.*clk_a/w OUTFILE' INFILE`

Comment: You are using BRE so would need to escape the pipe `|` or simply add extended functionality by adding the `-E` or `-r` flag. `sed -n '/clk_a.*clk_b\|clk_b.*clk_a/w OUTFILE' INFILE`

Comment: IMHO, `grep` is simpler for this Also, it is not clear what you want to find, please improve your example.

Comment: Do you mean you want lines starting with clk_a or clk_b and followed by clk_b if starting with clk_an and followed by clk_a if starting with clk_b? Are lines with 2x clk_a but no clk_b in them wanted? What about lines with 2x clk_b?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -n '/start/,/end/w outFile' file
```

or

```
sed -n '/first/!b;/second/!b;w outFile' file
```

The first solution will write out all lines between `start` and `end` including the lines containing `start` and `end`.

The second solution will write out all lines containing both `first`
and `second`.

N.B. If the pattern occurs multiple times within the file all occurrences will be output.

---

The second solution could be shortened:

```
sed -n '/first/!b;/second/w outFile' file
```

If you were want `first` or `second` and `third`:

```
sed -n '/first\|second/!b;/third/w outFile' file
```

or

```
sed -n '/first/ba;/second/!b;/third/!b;:a;w outFile' file
```

depending on where you were to place parenthesis.

Comment: @JasonZhang Please consider accepting ✅the answer if it  does what you need so that potong is recognised and other people know it works. Thank you. An upvote  is also appreciated.